# Is the usage of the word "Feiern+mit jdm seinen Geburtstag" more prevalent in written Language than "jds Geburtstag Feiern" alone?

Tags: word-choice, letter

> Schade, dass es dir nicht so gut geht und meinen Geburtstag (mit mir) nicht feiern konntest.

Answer (score 1):

> Schade, dass es dir nicht so gut geht und **du** mein**en** Geburtstag **nicht** mit mir feiern konntest.

The *nicht* should negate *mit mir* because it suggests the other person made a small celebration (coughing: »Yay!«) for you even if she could not come to the party.

But your question was if

> Schade, dass es dir nicht so gut geht und **du** mein**en** Geburtstag **nicht** feiern konntest.

was more prevalent. Well, it depends. That latter sentence suggests the sick person was unable to celebrate, but she should had! This isn't too friendly.

The reason is as in the sentence above. Adding **mit mir** suggests there was an encounter or party and this letter of sorrow is about the sickness and meeting each other.

Comment: But what if I use "dass du meinen Geburtstag mit mir nicht feiern konntest".Do you think it has the meaning "that you couldn't celebrate my birthday by my side" because you were sick

Comment: That one suggests you two met but the other person was grumpy and could not celebrate.